# Access table field to save multiple format types in a Number data type field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a access table with one of the fields "Dimension" to record the side length of a square. The Datatype for Dimension field as Number with field size Decimal, scale 2 and format 0.00. The values for the fields are 25.00, 27.50, 18.65...

But now I want to use the same field to save the dimensions of a rectangle with format 25.00X35.00(lengthXbreadth) with two decimals. Is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a Number column can only hold one value. Ideally you should create two columns: Length and Breadth to hold dimensions of 2D shapes. If you really have to have them in the same field -not recommended- you could use a Short Text column (and add various controls, like validation rules, to guarantee that the text entered follows your lenghthxbreadth format), but it would be pain to use it afterwards.